# Getting Primary Channel of Public Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, member, channel, microsoft-graph-teams

Can we get the Primary Channel of a Public Team using the Graph API, if the user is not the member of the Team.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you meaning with Delegated, as opposed to Application, permissions?

Comment: App Permissions. However, could you suggest if it is supported in either way. Thanks!

Comment: If the user is not a member, then delegated will have issues, so application is better. What do you mean about "get the primary channel" though? Get in what way?

Comment: call to the '/teams/{GroupId}/primaryChannel' endpoint from an App throws the error: 'Failed to execute Skype backend request GetThreadRequest'

Comment: what do mean primary channel? If you are trying to get the a particular channel in the team you need to use [get channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). try if that helps.